# Using `app_crypto!` `Public` type as `AccountId` in the runtime

Tags: runtime, frame-system, accountid

In our project, we have on-chain storage items equivalent to the type `AuthorityId` which is the `Public` type coming out of the `app_crypto!` macro in `sp-authority-discovery`.

We would like to configure the runtime in a way that the `<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId` is `AuthorityId`,
because our dispatchable function needs to be able to associate the caller aka `origin: OriginFor<T>` with the stored `AuthorityId`.

As the signature check `let who = ensure_signed!(origin)?;` gives us `T::AccountId` or concretely `<Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId` we set `type AccountId = AuthorityId` in the `impl frame_system::Config for Runtime` block, which should allow us to make sure that each caller of extrinsics is identified using `AuthorityId`.

This results in the following:

```rust
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `execute_block` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<Public, ..., ..., ...>>, ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
     --> /home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/runtime/src/lib.rs:699:15
      |
  699 |             Executive::execute_block(block);
      |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
      |
     ::: /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/76fed9b/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs:44:1
      |
  44  | pub struct UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>
      | -------------------------------------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Checkable<ChainContext<Runtime>>`
      |
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/target/debug/wbuild/gensyn-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/gensyn_runtime-13d0535547ae2d3c.long-type-6182207052186516563.txt'
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `_sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<sp_authority_discovery::app::Public, RuntimeCall, sp_authority_discovery::app::Signature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>: Checkable<ChainContext<Runtime>>`
```

This indicates to me that using `app_crypto!` types does not work out of the box here, as the extrinsics do not implement `Checkable<_>`.

What is the proper way of using types such as `AuthorityId` as `AccountId`?

Edit:

Alternatively specifying the associated type as such:
`type AccountId = <<AuthoritySignature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccound>::AccountId;`
gives hundreds of errors including the following, potentially more useful error:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `sp_authority_discovery::app::Signature: _sp_runtime::traits::Verify` is not satisfied
     --> /home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/runtime/src/lib.rs:876:3
      |
  876 | /         fn authorities() -> Vec<AuthorityDiscoveryId> {
  877 | |             let current_session_index = <pallet_session_info::Pallet<Runtime>>::session_index();
  878 | |             let earliest_stored_session = <pallet_session_info::Pallet<Runtime>>::earliest_stored_session();
  879 | |
  ...   |
  897 | |
  898 | |         }
      | |_________^ the trait `_sp_runtime::traits::Verify` is not implemented for `sp_authority_discovery::app::Signature`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `_sp_runtime::traits::Verify`:
                AnySignature
                MultiSignature
                sp_core::ecdsa::Signature
                sp_core::ed25519::Signature
                sp_core::sr25519::Signature
```

Manually implementing `Verify` here seems weird as I would have expected that a `Signature` should always be verifiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that works inside the extrinsic is the following:

```rust
let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
let who: AuthorityId = sp_application_crypto::sr25519::Public::from_raw(who.into()).into();
```

This keeps the `AccountId` as:

```rust
pub type AccountId = <MultiSignature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;
```

I hope this solution is the right way to do the conversion.

If not, please let me know!

Comment: Hi, it has an error at ''into''. Could you please check my code? https://github.com/kajqt/pos-node/blob/dev/frame/babe/src/lib.rs