# How to convert `AccountId` to `AuthorityId`

Tags: consensus, babe, accountid

```
  699 |                 acc_vec.push((account_id, userInfo.weight.saturated_into::<u64>()));
      |                               ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Public`, found associated type
      |
      = note:       expected struct `sp_consensus_babe::app::Public`
              found associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
      = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId` to `sp_consensus_babe::app::Public`
```

I am trying to customize BABE, and converting an selected `AccountId` into `AuthorityId` for the next epoch. How to solve this error? Thank you.

My code

```
let mut acc_vec: Vec<(AuthorityId, u64)> = vec![];
for (account_id, userInfo) in UserBoard::<T>::iter(){
    acc_vec.push((account_id, userInfo.weight.clone().saturated_into::<u64>()));
}
```

Please checkout branch `dev`: https://github.com/kajqt/pos-node

Comment: Check [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7896/using-app-crypto-public-type-as-accountid-in-the-runtime/8026#8026) answer, it might help

Comment: @magecnion: it said "= note: `Public` and `sp_consensus_babe::app::Public` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
  note: `Public` is defined in crate `sp_core`"